# Can't add FontAwesome 5 in slick arrow

Tags: css, slick.js, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to style Slick arrow with CSS pseudo-elements with FontAwesome 5. From FontAwesome's documentation I also added this line before loding FantAwesome.

```
<script>
    FontAwesomeConfig = { searchPseudoElements: true };
</script>
```

My CSS is below :

```
.slick-arrow {
    font-size: 0;
    position: absolute;
    color: #34495E;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 15%;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 15px 12px;
}
.slick-prev {
    left: -15px;
    text-align: left;
}
.slick-prev:after {
    content: "\f16c";
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.slick-next {
    right: -15px;
    text-align: right;
}
.slick-next:after {
    font: 40px/1 'ionicons';
    content: "\f3d1";
}
```

If I remove

> font-size: 0

then Font Awesome icons are showing but with the text "previous/next". I only need icon without text.

Comment: share your full code so we see the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats how it should be

i would **recommend** you to use the selector like that the name of the slide class then the arrows classes

```
.your-class .slide-prev
```

explained with details in [Fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/web-fonts-with-css#pseudo-elements)

and my example only for using CSS

This code only for using **SVG**

```
<script>
    FontAwesomeConfig = { searchPseudoElements: true };
</script>
```

```js
  $('.your-class').slick();
```

```css
    body {
      background-color: pink;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    .container {
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 1rem auto;
      background-color: #eee;
    }

    .your-class .item {
      height: 500px;
    }

    .your-class .slick-prev {
      left: -35px;
    }

    .your-class .slick-next {
      right: -35px;
    }

     .your-class .slick-prev:before {
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
      font-weight: 900; 
      content: "\f104";
      font-size: 3rem;
    }

      .your-class .slick-next:before {
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
      font-weight: 900; 
      content: "\f105";
      font-size: 3rem;
    }
```

```html
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="your-class">
        <div class="item">your content</div>
        <div class="item">your content</div>
        <div class="item">your content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `you don't need to do that` --> he need to do that when using the JS version and you are using the CSS version which is not the same

Comment: @TemaniAfif he wrote in his post `I'm trying to style Slick arrow with CSS pseudo-elements with FontAwesome 5.`  and `CSS pseudo-elements` doesn't need JS

Comment: read this https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#pseudo-elements ;)

Comment: I know but he didn't say that he is talking about SVG i know the documentation very well i was facing his issue as well that's why i am saying that

Comment: He don't need to say he's taking about SVG or not .. I am talking about your answer, you said *you don't need to do that* which is not true because you don't know which version he included in his code [the JS or the CSS] and most of the people don't even know it's about SVG  ... Then in his question he said that it's working when we remove `font-size:0` so there is somehow an issue with his code not the use of FA5. By the way your answer is working but I don't see how it solve his issue [you have no idea about his HTML btw].

Comment: Sorry for not replying soon. The main problem was I didn't add `font-weight: 900;`. After adding this line on pseudo elements it solved.